# Переключение горячей клавишей между табами в полно экраном виде в Phpstorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Всем привет, может кто подскажет как то можно переключаться горячей клавишей между табами в полно экраном виде в Phpstorm? в настройках пробежался не увидел подобного.. но может вдруг пропустил чтото

[image]

Comment: Попробуйте ctrl+tab

Comment: в рамках одного активного окна табы переключает